# Internal IP address of Raspberry Pi is changing

Tags: raspbian, connection, vnc, static-ip, laptop

I am trying to connect my `Raspberry Pi 2 model B V 1.1` using Raspbian Wheezy to my laptop that is connected to the internet using Wi-Fi and my LAN port is empty. I followed [The best way to connect Raspberry Pi to laptop display](http://diyhacking.com/connect-raspberry-pi-to-laptop-display/) to connect and everything is fine and working but my laptop assigned IP to the Ethernet is `192.168.137.1` so I tried to connect using `VNC Viewer` but that is saying that `The connection was refused by the host computer`.

After this I tried to find out my IP address from Raspberry and I got `192.168.137.XX` or sometimes `192.XXX.XXX.XXX` means totally different IP addresses as shown in the laptop Ethernet. When I used the Raspberry Pi's IP address in VNC Viewer then it's working fine but when I do not have a display connected to my Raspberry Pi then how can I know the internal IP address of my Raspberry Pi?

Comment: To make this setup work, you need to know the exact IP addresses of host and raspi. How are you connecting to the raspi, are you using SSH or monitor+keyboard? In most circumstances, it is easier to just use DHCP to let the router assign an IP to the host. Connect raspi to host, and either [bridge](https://www.hackster.io/Anwaarullah/sharing-wifi-with-raspberry-pi-using-a-lan-cable-ae1f44) WiFi and Ethernet connection or use Internet Connection Sharing. For the IP addresses, see [this ICS guide](http://www.utilizewindows.com/internet-connection-sharing-ics-on-windows-systems/)

Comment: I tried to assign automatic IP to my Ethernet using DHCP Enabled and first found my assigned IP to my Ethernet port using `ipconfig` in windows but the IP that is showing there is different from the IP showing in Raspberry Pi. Now what should I do?

Comment: I am new to this so I followed every step from the upper link but the problem is this that the IP showing in my windows is different and the IP showing in raspberry is different so How can I know the IP of raspberry in windows when I will not have any display to Raspberry?

Comment: I tried to `ping raspberrypi` in windows to know the IP of RaspberryPi but saying that `Ping request could not find host raspberrypi. Please check the name and try again.`

Comment: You're confusing the network interfaces. WiFi connects laptop to router (and internet). WiFi should use DHCP. Ethernet shares WiFI connection with raspi. Ethernet should have a fixed IP (by default: `192.168.137.1` in Win >= 7, `192.168.0.1` in Win <= XP. Now, you *know* that the DHCP server on your Ethernet interface assigns IPs incrementally. So the IP of the raspi is probably `192.168.0.2` (WinXP) or `192.168.137.2` (Win>=7). Try `ping 192.168.137.2`.

Comment: I am doing same and yes, My IP in Raspberry Pi is automatically increasing with no logic. Now after resting all setting as you shared above in my Windows 7, I got `192.168.137.130` IP in RaspberryPi. Means its changing at no logic so how can I know the perfect one later...???

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got a way to find out my assigned IP to Raspberry Pi so that now I can use that in VNCViewer to connect it.

Comment: Happy to help :) Feel free to share the answer / working configuration for the benefit of other users.

Comment: Answer shared. You can edit it more to make it a general answer to help others too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following the steps in the shared link in question, I wan unable to find out my Raspberry Pi real IP address because my Ethernet IP address is altered by Raspberry Pi. So when I will not have the display then how can I know the IP address of my Raspberry Pi? But its solved now. Just follow the below steps...

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install samba
```

Now after installing this on Raspberry Pi, just type `ping <hostname>` in your Windows CMD and that will return the current correct IP of raspberry pi that you can use in VNCViewer to connect. The default hostname of Raspberry Pi is **raspberrypi** . You can change it also by editing **[`/etc/hosts`](http://www.howtogeek.com/167195/how-to-change-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-devices-hostname/)**.

Comment: Don't change `hostname` by editing `/etc/hosts` do it properly; usually by running `raspi-config`. Editing `/etc/hosts` only does half the job.